# MySQL Delete String and everything behind that string

Tags: mysql

If I am honest, I saw many answers but I don't quite get it.

I have a column that contains the hashtag character `#` and I need to delete it and everything behind it. There is only one `#`. I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '#', -1)
```

But it didn't work.

Is that possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: probably you should use `1` instead of `-1`

Comment: What programming language are you using? You could read the values into a string, manipulate it and then update the database.

Comment: @AdmiralNoiseBottom That will potentially require thousands or millions of queries, depending on how big the table is. Since MySQL can do it directly, why do it that way?

Comment: @Lashane Post it as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar, I made my comment because I'm not an SQL expert and my suggestion would have gotten them out of trouble if it was a once off.

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter in the `substring_index` is the count of the second parameter appearance.  So if you send a 1 as third parameter, you will keep with the whole word up to the first appearance of the character # (not included)

```
SET my_col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '#', 1)
```

wawawa#dsdf will result into wawawa